# What anime is this GIF of a grey-haired boy eating from?

Tags: black-butler

[image]

I tried google image search but it didn't find anything =_=

Answer (score 12):

Kuroshitsuji: Book of Circus

Episode: 4

Character Name: Doll

This occurs around 19:24 when Ciel and 'Doll' are eating what is suppose to be fish and chips. In this particular scene/picture that you've included, Doll was praising Sebastians cooking skills.

> ***Doll:*** Black's cooking is brilliant.